# Check several date formats using DateTime.TryParse()

Tags: c#

I'm using a method to validate textboxes.

```
    public bool ValidateDateTimeTextBoxes(params TextBox[] textBoxes)
    {
        DateTime value = DateTime.Today;
        //string dateFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy";

        foreach (var textBox in textBoxes)
        {
            if (!DateTime.TryParse(textBox.Text, out value))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

I want to check the format too. It requires `mm/dd/yyyy`, but want it to be `dd/mm/yyyy`

Comment: look up TryParseExact

Comment: Title, title, I could not understand "but"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22.aspx)

```
DateTime dt;

DateTime.TryParseExact(textBox.Text, 
                       "dd/MM/yyyy", 
                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                       DateTimeStyles.None, 
                       out dt);
```

If you want to check multiple formats as you updated in your question then you can do using another overload method of `TryParseExact` which takes `format` parameter as array of string.

```
string[] formats = { "dd/MM/yyyy", "MM/dd/yyyy" };
DateTime.TryParseExact(txtBox.Text, 
                       formats, 
                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                       DateTimeStyles.None, 
                       out value));
```

Please take care of format string.  As you have mentioned format as `dd/mm/yyyy`. Here `mm` represents the `minute` not the month. Use `MM` for the month representation.

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(textBox.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out outDt))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 public bool ValidateDateTimeTextBoxes(params TextBox[] textBoxes)
    {
        DateTime value = DateTime.Now;
        //string dateFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy";

        foreach (var textBox in textBoxes)
        {
            if (!DateTime.TryParse(textBox.Text,"dd/mm/yyyy",new CultureInfo("en-US"), 
                          DateTimeStyles.None out value))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `TryParseExact`

Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its DateTime equivalent. The format of the string representation must match a specified format exactly. The method returns a value that indicates whether the conversion succeeded.

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(DateValue, 
                       "dd/mm/yyyy", 
                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                       DateTimeStyles.None, 
                       out outDatetime);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `TryParseExact` instead which is also faster.
Example:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string dateString = "27/05/2012"; // <-- Valid
        string dtformat = "dd/mm/yyyy";
        DateTime dateTime;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, dtformat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime))
        {
           Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any reference when you say that `TryParseExact` is faster?

Comment: I had found this blog post (  http://blog.joachim.at/?p=42 ) , here from an older question.