# Convert string to specific date format C#

Tags: c#, string, datetime, date-formatting

I have a problem to convert string to date format in C#.
I'm getting the data through a row of a gridview:

```
string shipping_date = row["Shipping_Date"].ToString();
```

with format: 27/08/2015 00:00:00 but want convert to the format "yyyyMMdd".

Already used the method DateTime.TryParse, but without success...
After getting the date, it is to extract to a txt file (which I have to work). I've seen some identical issues here, but none worked for me.

Someone can help me convert to "yyyyMMdd"?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check several date formats using DateTime.TryParse()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16767917/check-several-date-formats-using-datetime-tryparse)

Comment: Is the string int the cell yyyyMMdd and want to be able to parse that, or is it dd/MM/yyyy... and you want to convert it to the former? If you have already `DateTime` object then you don't need to parse at all, just do a `.ToString("yyyyMMdd")`. Please formulate the question clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not clear, I only guess you want something like this

```
var input = "27/08/2015 00:00:00";
var output = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                     .ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize the formatting in `ToString()`.  You would simply do `ToString(yyyyMMdd)`.  That would use your formatting.  The notations are:

- Month: M (1), MM (02)
- Day: d (1), dd (02)
- Day of Week: ddd, dddd
- Year: y (5), yy (15), yyy (015), yyyy (2015)
- Hour: h (1), hh (02)
- Minute: m (1), mm (02)
- Second: s (1), ss (02)

Answer (score 0):

There's a good chance the value is *already* a `DateTime`.  Therefore, you should probably be doing this:

```
string shipping_date = String.Empty;
if(row["Shipping_Date"] != DBNull.Value)
     shipping_date = ((DateTime)row["Shipping_Date"]).ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```